# How to create a frequency table and update is as chunks of data are loaded, in Python?

Tags: python, large-data, large-files

I have a massive table (several billion rows), and I need to analyze two numerical variables within it by a) creating a frequency table and b) creating distribution plots.

VarA has a range of 0.00 to 1.00 (in 0.01 increments)
VarB is distributed around 0.00 (in 0.01 increments)

I want to iterate over reading 1,000 rows then updating the frequency table. I have tried the following code:

```py
c_size = 1000

result = {'A': dict(), 'B': dict()}

def update_dict(key, val):
    if val not in result[key]:
         result[key][val] = 1
    else:
         result[key][val] += 1

for data_chunk in pd.read_csv('data.csv', names=['ValA','ValB'], skiprows=10, chunksize=c_size):
    for row in data_chunk:
        valA, valB = row
        update_dict('A', valA)
        update_dict('B', valB)

print(result['A'])
print(result['B'])
```

#### Edits

1. Updated code with suggestions from @peter-du

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working code. Thanks, @Peter-Du for your help.

```py
c_size = 1000
result = {'VarA': dict(), 'VarB': dict()}
def update_dict(key, val):
   if val not in result[key]:
       result[key][val] = 1
   else:
       result[key][val] += 1
reader = pd.read_csv('file.csv', names=['VarA','VarB'], skiprows=10, chunksize=c_size)
for i, data_chunk in enumerate(reader):
    for row in data_chunk.values:
        valA, valB = row
        update_dict('VarA', np.round(valA,2))
        update_dict('VarB', np.round(valB,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it process lighter, I think you should store processed value in the dictionary instead of two separate tables.

To iterate every 1000 rows in a billion of rows, I think you should use the generator mechanism (refer to https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)

I show a small example of that below.

```
input_data = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [2, 4]]
result = {'A': dict(), 'B': dict()}

def update_dict(key, val):
    if val not in result[key]:
         result[key][val] = 1
    else:
         result[key][val] += 1


# Since the list is not too big, I use for loop to iterate.
# However, you can apply the generator mechanism for the code below.
for row in input_data:
    valA, valB = row
    update_dict('A', valA)
    update_dict('B', valB)

print(result['A'])
>>> {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1}

print(result['B'])
>>> {2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2}

# Then, you can use these two dictionaries to create two separate tables
# You can also join two tables together using Pandas data frame
```

To plot the distribution, I would suggest using seaborn (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) for the beautiful plot.

Comment: I get: "valA, valB = row
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: May I know your input data and its type? I tested the code in my local machine with the shown the `input_data` and it works fine.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code I used last. Essentially, the data is a large CSV table with two numerical values (a few billion rows).

Comment: I see, your `data_chunk` might be a type of pandas data frame. So, when you iterate through it, it only takes the index of each row. You can test it by printing your `data_chunk` or `row`.

I would suggest modifying the line with for loop into `for row in data_chunk.values:` so that you can receive the np.ndarray for the processing.